# Why doesn't the MATLAB surf function work with single precision data?

Tags: matlab, precision, color-mapping

I have a matrix of values of type single that I want to plot as a surface. When I attempt to use the surf function in MATLAB, I get an error specifying I need to use uint8 or double instead:

```
x=peaks; %# Initialize x to a matrix of doubles
surf(x); %# No problem when x is of type double
```

Now I'll try singles:

```
x=single(peaks);
surf(x);
```

Gives the following error:

```
Warning: CData must be double or uint8. 
Warning: CData must be double or uint8.
```

Well that's unfortunate. I guess I'll have to increase to double precision for the colormap:

```
x=single(peaks);
surf(x,double(x));
```

Works just fine. But just for kicks let's try uint8 as well:

```
x=single(peaks);
surf(x,uint8(x));
```

Yields the following:

```
Warning: CData must be double or single unless it is used only as a texture data 
Warning: CData must be double or single unless it is used only as a texture data
```

What the heck MATLAB? Make up your mind! So why is it that I have to use extra memory in the form of double precision to denote the colormap for the `surf` function? Even when MATLAB error text tells me I can use uint8 **or** single, depending on whichever one I **didn't use**?

Answer (score 1):

Love the question.

Not sure if you saw [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/279332) or not, but it at least addresses your same disgust.  Sounds like the Michael was disappointed with the performance in the `uint8` algorithm in that he describes that it appears to create more computational work for itself with a plot that doesn't meet his aesthetic needs.  I tried it with the `peaks` sample and this is what I get:

[image: Raw Peaks Data]

Then I added an offset to get all the plot.

[image: Offset Peaks Data]

Eh, it's fine I guess.  Here's the code, hope this has been useful.

```
% Test code from Matlab Central
a=256*rand(5);
b=uint8(a);
figure;
surf(b,'facecolor','texturemap')

% get the example peaks data
% and plot without any scaling
x = peaks;
figure;
surf(uint8(x),'facecolor','texturemap')

% get the offset to keep all the data positive
% not pretty but functional
xp = x-min(min(x))+1;
figure;
surf(uint8(xp),'facecolor','texturemap')
```

Comment: It's an interesting solution, but doesn't really fit my problem. I need more resolution on the colormap. I think I'm just going to go with a solution `surf(x,double(x))`.